# Computer restarted during upgrade now I can't log in, how do I fix it?

Tags: upgrade

I was upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04 and the upgrade froze, and then booted me out to the login screen. From there I can't do anything, trying to log in just returns me to the login screen. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to backup your data from Live CD and reformat and install a clean ubuntu

Comment: How would I backup my data using a Live CD? I'm kind of hopeless when it comes to anything technical.

Comment: insert your ubuntu install cd into your cd-drive.  boot from it and choose try ubuntu. When it boots you can copy your files into a cd or a removable usb drive. when done install ubuntu again

Comment: I'll need to burn one, but thanks, I'll try that in the morning.

Comment: if you have any further question don't hesitate to ask them. and you find my answer helpful please don't forget to mark it as answer and upvote

Comment: I definitely will! Just to make sure, I will be able to access my files from the LiveCD environment? I used one before a long time ago to fix another problem and got a completely blank test desktop.

Comment: when entering live cd you can mount your partition and see your home directory

Answer (score 0):

OP posted:

> I was able to solve the problem with information provided [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2062956). My gratitude does go out to Kamil for their assistance too, though!